# How create a turtles with memory on NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I need some help to write a code that: a turtle explores the world and dies and the next turtle that will be created will take the same path as the previous turtle and so on, so the last turtle can take any path that any other turtle that came before it. If anyone has any ideas how I can do this or some model I can explore that idea. I am very grateful

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need two lists: one `turtles-own` list, that contains the path (either the `patch-here` or a list of specific coordinates). Before the turtles dies, you can save the path in a global "path-list".

When a turtle shouldn't walk its own path, but should "imitate" the walk of another, it can get a random path from the path-list with `one-of` and then `move-to` (in case you saved the patch or `setxy` in case you saved the coordinates) the first element of the list. The you should delete the first item, so that in the next step the turtle will move to the next position.

Maybe the concept of breeds is interesting for you to differentiate between turtles, that create their own path, and turtles, that follow them.

```
turtles-own 
[
  path
  imitation-path
]
globals [path-list]

to setup-random
  ca
  reset-ticks
  set path-list []
  crt 2
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    pen-down
    set path (list patch-here)
  ]
end

to go-random
  tick
  ask turtles 
  [
    if ticks > 10
    [
      set path-list lput path path-list
      die
    ]
    move-to one-of neighbors
    set path lput patch-here path
  ]
end

to setup-imitators
  crt 2
  [
    set imitation-path one-of path-list
    move-to first imitation-path
    set imitation-path remove-item 0 imitation-path
  ]  
end

to imitate
  ask turtles 
  [
    if empty? imitation-path
    [ die ]
    move-to first imitation-path
    set imitation-path remove-item 0 imitation-path
  ]
end
```